# PMTA Timeout Centos 7

Tags: iptables, smtp, email-server, timeout

I have an issue with PMTA which not sending any emails from my server and all connections with others are timeout!

**Timed out, status = ETIMEDOUT while connecting from subdomain.                                                                                                                                                            myserver.tld (My_Server_Ip) to reception.mail-tester.com (94.23.206.89)**

I have pinged my server from my computer and its working!

I have pinged 94.23.206.89 from my server and its working!

My server is using VestaPanel as a control panel and I wonder if its firewall might be blocking the connections!

What do you think about this?

Below is my config file :

```
#smtp-port 25
smtp-listener SERVER_IP:25
<source 0/0>
    log-connections yes
    log-commands    yes      # WARNING: verbose!
  allow-unencrypted-plain-auth yes
</source>
sync-msg-create false
sync-msg-update false
run-as-root no
log-file /var/log/pmta/log        # logrotate is used for rotation

<acct-file /var/log/pmta/acct.csv>
#    move-to /opt/myapp/pmta-acct   # configure as fit for your application
#    move-interval 5m

    max-size 50M
</acct-file>

# transient errors (soft bounces)
<acct-file /var/log/pmta/diag.csv>
  move-interval 1d
  delete-after never
  records t
</acct-file>

#
# spool directories
#

spool /var/spool/pmta

http-mgmt-port 1983
http-access 127.0.0.1 admin
http-access 0/0 monitor
http-access SERVER_IP admin




# BEGIN: USERS/VIRTUAL-MTA / VIRTUAL-MTA-POOL /  VIRTUAL-PMTA-PATTERN

#<spool /var/spool/pmta>
#</spool>
<smtp-user xxxx>
    password xxxxx
    source {smtpuser-auth}
</smtp-user>
<smtp-user xxxxx>
    password xxxxx
    source {smtpuser-auth}
</smtp-user>
<source {smtpuser-auth}>
    smtp-service yes
    always-allow-relaying yes
    require-auth true
    process-x-virtual-mta yes
    default-virtual-mta pmta-pool
    remove-received-headers true
    add-received-header false
    hide-message-source true
</source>
#BEGIN VIRTUAL MTAS 
<virtual-mta pmta-vmta1>
smtp-source-host SERVER_IP subdomain.myserver.tld
domain-key dkim,*,/home/admin/conf/mail/subdomain.myserver.tld/dkim.pem
<domain *>
max-msg-rate 400/h
</domain>
</virtual-mta> <domain myserver.tld>
route [127.0.0.1]:25
</domain>
#END VIRTUAL MTAS


<virtual-mta-pool pmta-pool>
virtual-mta pmta-vmta1
</virtual-mta-pool>

# END: USERS/VIRTUAL-MTA / VIRTUAL-MTA-POOL /  VIRTUAL-PMTA-PATTERN

<source 127.0.0.1>
    always-allow-api-submission yes
    add-message-id-header yes
    retain-x-job yes
    retain-x-virtual-mta yes
    verp-default yes
    process-x-envid yes
    process-x-job yes
    jobid-header X-Mailer-RecptId
    process-x-virtual-mta yes
</source>

<domain myserver.tld>
route [127.0.0.1]:25
</domain>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your host may be blocking outbound port 25. You can verify this quickly with:

```
telnet reception.mail-tester.com:25
```

If successful, you'll see:

```
220 mail-tester.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
```

If you receive a connection timed out error, it's blocked.